# Vue.js why does the "updateXY" function gets called with "event" as parameter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

So recently I started learning the Vue.js framework and I found a code snippet. I don't know why does the `"updateXY"` function gets called with the `"event"` as parameter, even though it is not specified.

### index.html

```
<div id="vue-app">
    <div id="canvas" v-on:mousemove="updateXY">
      ({{ x }}, {{ y }}) 
    </div>
</div>
```

### app.js

```
new Vue({
el: "#vue-app",
data: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},
methods: {
  updateXY: function (event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying what function to get called by the event.

The emitter of the event decides what (and how many) parameters to pass.

Your function parameter declaration is a way for you to access the passed parameters and not to a way to restrict access to calling the function.

A function in JS can be called with any number of parameters, independent of the declaration. The are all accessible via the `arguments` variable.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes inside an event handler function, you might see a parameter specified with a name such as event, evt, or simply e. This is called the event object, and it is automatically passed to event handlers to provide extra features and information.

Please refer [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_objects) docs